# Convert to current time zone in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timezone

When i fetch date from Oracle i add inline query in my server code as ,

```
cast((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Amsterdam') AS DATE)
```

The same above format how to implement to the below code,

```
dim currentDate as datetime= DateTime.Now
```

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: `DateTime.Now` already is in the current time zone. It is the current date and time on the local machine with a `Kind` of `Local`. What exactly are you trying to achieve that that doesn't already? You can call `ToUniversalTime` and `ToLocalTime` to witch between local and UTC. If you want to be able to support other time zones then you need to use the `DateTimeOffset` type.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle code shown gets the current date and time in Amsterdam, and truncates the time by casting it to a `DATE` type.

The equivalent VB.Net code would be:

```
Dim dt as Date
dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow, "W. Europe Standard Time").Date
```

Note the `.Date` at the end.  That sets the time portion to zero, similar to how you were truncating the time in Oracle.  If you don't want that, then leave `.Date` off.

This also assumes you're running on Windows.  If you're running .NET on a non-Windows platform, then you can use the same string as you did on oracle, `"Europe/Amsterdam"`.